# Creating reminder from a arrayList in android

Tags: android

i have created a dietchart arrayList with specific timeperiod, now i want to create a reminder which will notify when it is time for a specific diet with sound.

Comment: why cant you create sticky service which runs in background and check if current time matches any time in your arraylist and shows popup or notification according to your requirement

Comment: i dont know how to do so,this idea came to me before but could not find a way to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this question is little bit old but it can still help to other users. You have to use alarm manager for triggering at specific time.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,<here set time when you want to trigger>,<here you can set time to repeat after trigering continusosly>,pintent);
```